# Conversion Application - for android

Tags: android

Im trying to create an currency conversion app but nothing happens when i click on the convert button. Here is the code i followed the tutorial.

```
package com.currencyconverter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class currencyconverter extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


TextView dollars;
TextView euros;
RadioButton dtoe;
RadioButton etod;
Button convert;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

dollars = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.dollars);
euros = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.euros);
dtoe = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.dtoe);
dtoe.setChecked(true);
etod = (RadioButton)this.findViewById(R.id.etod);
convert = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Convert);
convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (dtoe.isChecked()) {
convertDollarsToEuros();
}
if (etod.isChecked()) {
convertEurosToDollars();
}

}
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

protected void convertEurosToDollars(){
double val = Double.parseDouble(euros.getText().toString());
dollars.setText(Double.toString(val/0.67));

}
protected void convertDollarsToEuros(){
double val = Double.parseDouble(dollars.getText().toString());
euros.setText(Double.toString(val*0.67));



}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});
```

to

```
convert.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Why? If you can't answer this question you need to study more Java....
Just kidding... the reason is that you are setting an empty click listener. On the other hand, your `Activity` implements the `OnClickListener` interface and the `onClick` method of that implementation is what you want to execute (not the empty you set to the button).

Comment: Hi Cristian. Everything works. But for one small issue.Example, If I select dollars to euros,  do not enter any values and I press convert than it says "The application currency converter (process com.currency converter)has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. If I can get this to go away than my app is running 100%.

Comment: Have you checked dollars and euros text box having null values or not? Do check in log cat because I guess that these text boxes throw null pointer exceptions while there is not any value in that text boxes....

Comment: @user: besides Prasham's suggestion... make sure to catch any other possible exception... what about a `NumberFormatException`?